VBA Excel Initialize form - variable not found
I am trying to open a textfile via a hyperlink in a Form in Excel.
So in column B there is a hyperlink that directs the user to a textfile.  Since the textfile is on a SharePoint environment, I want it to open in a UserForm instead of a browser.  The file needs to be editable.
The filepath is correctly found Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(), but somehow it doesn't get passed into the public variable to be used in UserForm_Initialize().  So when the form needs to be opened I get an error Path not found.
I can't seem to get my head around it.
Code behind the sheet in Excel
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim frm As UserForm1 ' Declare a variable to hold the UserForm instance

    ' Extract the file name from the hyperlink's address
    fileName = Mid(Target.Address, InStrRev(Target.Address, "/") + 1)

    ' If the file has an extension, remove it
    If InStr(fileName, ".") > 0 Then
        fileName = Left(fileName, InStrRev(fileName, ".") - 1)
    End If

    ' Construct the file path assuming the Content folder is in the same directory as the workbook
    filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName & ".txt"
    Debug.Print "File Path in Worksheet_Initialize 1: " & filePath ' Debugging line

    ' Create a new instance of the UserForm
    Set frm = New UserForm1
    Debug.Print "File Path in Worksheet_Initialize 2: " & filePath ' Debugging line
    ' Set the file path and show the UserForm
    frm.filePath = filePath
    Debug.Print "File Path in Worksheet_Initialize 3 : " & filePath ' Debugging line
    
    frm.Show
End Sub

Code behing the UserForm1
Public filePath As String ' Store the file path
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim fileContent As String
    Dim fileNum As Integer
    Debug.Print "File Path in UserForm_Initialize: " & filePath ' Debugging line

    If filePath <> "" Then
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        fileNum = FreeFile
        Open filePath For Input As #fileNum
        fileContent = Input$(LOF(fileNum), #fileNum)
        Close #fileNum

        ' Display the file content in the TextBox
        Me.TextBox1.Text = fileContent
    Else
        MsgBox "File path not found."
        Unload Me
    End If
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error loading file: " & Err.Description
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click()
    ' Save the content from the TextBox back to the file
    Dim fileNum As Integer
    Dim fileContent As String

    fileContent = Me.TextBox1.Text ' Ensure you have a TextBox named TextBox1

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    fileNum = FreeFile
    Open filePath For Output As fileNum
    Print #fileNum, fileContent
    Close fileNum

    MsgBox "File saved successfully!"
    Unload Me
    filePathSet = False ' Reset the flag after use
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error saving file: " & Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    ' Close the form without saving
    Unload Me
End Sub


Move Public filePath As String from the userform to a normal module and remove the Dim filePath As String from the Worksheet event code.

Your userform_Initialize event runs as soon as you instantiate the form. This means that any variables or properties you need set before this event runs, have not yet been set. I usually don't use that event, I create my own initialize sub which I can then call when I have set all properties.
Instead of using
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

simply change that to:
Public Sub Initialize().

Then in the calling routine right after
frm.filePath = filePath

you add:
frm.Initialize


Do you have an example?

Instead of using     Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    , I simply change that to:     Public Sub Initialize()    . Then in the calling routine right after    frm.filePath = filePath    you add:     frm.Initialize
